# Write Float in File Python3, without Converting it into String

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, file, dataframe, fwrite

I am trying to use loop to write float into a file, but the write function does not let it happen until I convert it into string or use format, which eventually converts it into string.

Is there any way that I can do it? I need the data inside the file to be in float, since later on the file data can be used to create graphs, thus strings can not be a way out.

Later on I need to use Termgraph Python3 library for this, and the data needs to be a float.

```
print("sequence","Sign","Values")
f = open("termdata.dat","w")
f.write("Sequence,Score\n")
for i in range(0,len(list_one)):
    value1 = list_two[i]
    value_ = q_score[value1]
    print(list_one[i],"\t", list_two[i],"\t", value_)
    str1 = str(list_one[i])
    float1 = float(value_)
    f.write(str1)
    f.write(",")
    f.write(str(float1))
    f.write("\n")
```

Comment: Data in a file cannot be a float. Data in a file is a string. When you read it out of the file, you can convert it back to a float. But the file will just contain ASCII text.

Comment: a file its self has no concept of a float or a string. its just a sequence of characters.

Comment: If you really want it retain it's format I would recommend using serialization such as pickling. However, you're still converting to a format and back and you're basically back in the same place you were with converting to a string.

Comment: In the second last line I am putting str format to show that it does convert to string as a compulsory. I want it to go in as a float.